# My /User directory permissions always changes… should I be worried?

Tags: macos, bash

I've noticed that my /Users directory on OSX always gets changed to "rwxrwxrwx"

I'm not sure how this is being changed? Only just started happening

Could it be malware or such?

Comment: If you have any remote connections or sharing DISABLE them in system preferences.

Comment: Does enabling them change the write access to allow all? ... or do you think that sharing is maybe allowing insecure access?

Comment: What version of iTunes do you have? The latest 11.2.1 has a fix for this as 11.2.0 showed this issue

Comment: disabling any remote access will tell you if the issue is local or remote

Comment: if the USERS becomes grayed out (invisible) then follow @Mark suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Install iTunes 11.2.1

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6251

Description: Upon each reboot, the permissions for the /Users and /Users/Shared directories would be set to world-writable, allowing modification of these directories. This issue was addressed with improved permission handling. For information on the general content of iTunes 11.2.1, see http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5434.